# Solving third degree polynomial $x^3+2x^2+6x+5=0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

> The polynomial $f(x) = x^3+2x^2+6x+5$ has one integer root. Find the integral and the other roots.

If the polynomial has an integer root, $a$, we can write: 
$$x^3+2x^2+6x+5=(x-a)(x^2+bx+c)=0$$ where b and c are unknown.

Yet, we do know that:

$b-a=2$

$c-ab=6$

$-ac=5$

However I can't find any way to solve this except trial and error. Am I missing some obvious insights here?

Comment: Look at the divisors of $5$ (positive or negative).  The integral root will be in there.

Comment: Where did e come from

Comment: See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem), especially the integral root theorem.

Comment: High school book, chapter on introduction to complex numbers.

Comment: Is it c. Rather than e

Comment: @ArchisWelankar: Surely $e$ was meant to be $c$.

Comment: @BrianTung obviously! Thanks. 5 is a prime => only divisible by one and itself!

Comment: snoram, as @BrianTung said, the possible choices for your root $a$ are $1,-1,5,-5.$ At least one of them works. Please check.

Comment: @ArchisWelankar fixed. thanks!

Comment: While I liked and upvoted both answers so far I think Brian's almost immediate comment was the best "answer", it uncovered the "obvious insight" that I was missing.

Answer (score 6):

We have 
$$
x^3+2x^2+6x+5=(x^2+x+5)(x+1),
$$
where we can take the alternating sum $-1+2-6+5=0$ to see the linear factor.

Comment: Does this method and vocabulary have a name?

Comment: If you write the polynomial as $(x - 1)(ax^2 + bx + c)$ what is the coefficient of (say) $x^3$? of the constant term, *etc*?

Comment: @snoram **Factor Theorem**: For polynomial $f(x)$, if $f(a)=0$, then $x-a$ is a factor of $f(x)$.  Actually, this is a special case of **Remainder Theorem**.

Answer (score 1):

I would hit this with the rational roots theorem.

The first and last coefficients are, respectively, $1$ and $5$.

We factor them both.

$$1\implies1$$

$$5\implies1,5$$

Start with the last coefficient's factors and divide it by the factors of the first coefficient.

$$\frac11,\frac51\implies1,5$$

Now we add a plus-minus sign:

$$\pm1,\pm5$$

And we guess/check.  This works great if you know one of the factors is a rational number (in the form of $x-\frac ab$)

From guess/check at this point, $x=-1$ is a factor.

There is a way to factor all cubic polynomials over $\mathbb{C}$, which, if you are interested in, I would recommend looking up the "Cubic formula".  Its rather messy though.